# use jquery to add event listener in .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which gets some data from an api:

```
aggregate_products.aggregate(products_to_aggregate)
        .then(data => {
            let formatted_products = dynamic_products.format_products_default_value(data)
            dynamic_products.add_products_to_form(formatted_products)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        .finally(function () {
            add_event_listeners_to_dynamic_products()
        })
```

this updates the DOM as well deeper in the code:

```
....
            $("#dynamic_products").empty()
            $(rendered).appendTo("#dynamic_products");
```

which all works fine. The problem I am having is I want to add event listeners to the new HTML rendered in the DOM. I do this in my finally() call above which runs `add_event_listeners_to_dynamic_products()` which runs the below code:

```
function add_event_listeners_to_dynamic_products() {
    $('#selected_products').find('.btn-danger').each(function (index, value) {
        $(value).bind("click", function (eventData) {
            console.log(eventData)
            remove_product_event(eventData)
        })
    });
}

function remove_product_event(event) {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
        dynamic_products.delete_selected_product(event.target.value)
    }
}
```

when I test this in the browser I can add the product but the loop to add the event listeners doesn't seem to run and the event handlers are not showing in my browser debug. The strange thing is if I run the below in the browser console:

```
$('#selected_products').find('.btn-danger').each(function (index, value) {
    $(value).bind("click", function (eventData) {
        console.log(eventData)
    })
});
```

my button:

```
        <div class="col-auto p-0">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="{{uuid_val}}">
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

edit update new working button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger far fa-trash-alt" value="{{uuid_val}}"></button>
```

it works find and binds the click event to the buttons I want binded. When I click them they also print the event data to the console. I cannot for the life of me figure out why `add_event_listeners_to_dynamic_products()` is not working?

overall im basically trying to dynamically add some products to a form from data I get from an api call. I also have added a button to remove individual products.

Comment: it seems that when add_event_listeners_to_dynamic_products is running ,your dom is not ready yet.

Comment: You don't need to loop through all elements, if your code run once the DOM is ready, all you need is to have it like this `$('#selected_products .btn-danger').click(..)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you look into [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Essentially, you'd want to register ONE event handler that isn't dependent on the content being populated (e.g. with your loop) instead of creating a new event handler for each item that all do the same thing (and require they are present in the DOM to bind/unbind the event handler).

Something like:

```
$("#selected_products").on("click", ".btn-danger", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).text(), event);
});
```

Comment: Thanks chase. I did try this approach originally. My delete button has an icon in it of a trash can which is in an <li> element. I found that the item was only removed if I clicked the edges of the outer button. The other issue I had is if the button wasnt exactly clicked the value stored in the button to remove the outer div was not passed to my event method and would fail

Comment: `btn-danger` should be a class on the overall button, and the button can contain any number of elements. As long as you don't have something additional that cancels or prevents propagation of events on the sub-elements (e.g. your icon) all clicks should register with this handler as long as the target is within the btn-danger button.

Comment: so I have uploaded my button html. How would I style my button without having the <li> trash can icon in it?

Comment: Just realized I can add the class to the button to style it. Have updated my original post, cheers for your help

Comment: I think I see what you might have been running into. The problem is you are using `target` on your event and checking for it being a button. You can instead just ignore all that since you have bound your event specifically to `.btn-danger` which we know is the button. You can use `$(event.currentTarget).val()` to get the value of the product you want to remove.